# How can I present live audio data (updating buffer) as an audio file in C

Tags: c, file, audio, live, vlc

I am recieving live audio as floating points in an updating array. I want this live data to present as a file that can b read by vlc media player. Can someone guide me how can I do that in C language?

/mudassar

Answer (score 2):

Does your operating system support pipes or fifos?  [You can stream input into VLC's standard input](http://wiki.videolan.org/Uncommon_uses) from the command line, or have your program write to the other end of a FIFO.   Only standard C library read/write calls are necessary.